# What are the synonyms to the phrase "balls to bones" from Matrix movie?

Tags: phrase-request, slang

That's a part of Oracle and Neo dialogue from Matrix:

> Oracle: So, what do you think? You think you're the one?
>
> Neo: I don't know.
>
> Oracle: You know what that means? It’s Latin. Means “Know thyself”. I’m going to let you in on a little secret. Being The One is just like being in love. No one can tell you you’re in love, you just know it. Through and through. **Balls to bones**. Well, I better have a look at you. Open your mouth, say Ahhh.

Question: what are the other ways to say the phrase "balls to bones"? Maybe more common or polite ones but widely used still?

Comment: "balls to bones" isn't a common idiom, I suspect it was made up for the movie, I can't find any written examples in google before the Matrix movie, although it has gained some currency since then.

Comment: Throughout my body, from my head to my feet, from my balls (testicles) (important part of my body) to my bones (a fundamental part of me).

Answer (score 16):

There's a synonym already in the quotation - "*through and through*".

Another common one would be "*head to toe*". Also, you can say someone has a quality "*down to their bones*".

Comment: "Through and through" is the obvious one.

Answer (score 0):

A similar phrase would also be - *"soup to nuts"*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soup_to_nuts):

> "Soup to nuts" is an American English idiom that conveys the meaning
> of "from beginning to end", derived from the description of a full
> course dinner. Soup to nuts may also refer to: Soup to Nuts, a 1930
> feature film starring the trio who later became the Three Stooges.